# How to create a partial type that return an error if too much information are given

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, partial

I would like to create a type that can accept a partial object but that can also return an error if we give to that object extra properties.

I tried that but it doesn't work like i want.

```
type Object = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
};

const fn = <T extends Partial<Object>>(param: T) => {
  console.log(param);
};

//should be ok and is ok
fn({ a: "a" });

//should be ok and is ok
fn({ a: "a", b: "b" });

//should not be ok BUT is ok 
fn({ a: "a", b: "b", d: "d" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like excess property checking doesn't work on the constraint of a generic. If you need that generic, you can replicate it manually with a mapped type

```js
const fn = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Object ? T[K] : `the key '${K & string}' does not exist in Object` }>(param: T) => {
  console.log(param);
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwFBSgQwFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gNxZRwHHnV3YDGTpltGAvnQzsA9hWJQAZhRRQAPABUoEAB7AIFACaF0UANoBpKJSgBrCCGESo8gLoFDKtZu1mLV+EgD81gzagEAA2AAC2hXKAByABI0QwAyIm5qPgioDWEIbQphYCVlMnFjDwCoPgA+AAowHBIcAFsCeQBKFDL0ehExYQAbCAA6buEqKpr6proBDAwAemnCYOEAV26NBmhhE1xNI20NjCkKtFwCACIcE9Lxqdn5pZW1qA2t1YLHk32KQ+OoM5OAGgYpzgFz4VxmcwWy1W2VycHWmxw21eMLeHy++B+5wBjB+wIBGlOGhB4yAA)

Answer (score 0):

How does this look?

```js
const fn = (
  props: {
    [k in "a" | "b" | "c"]?: string;
  }
) => {
  console.log(props);
};

//should be ok and is ok
fn({ a: "a" });

//should be ok and is ok
fn({ a: "a", b: "b" });

//should not be ok AND is not ok
fn({ a: "a", b: "b", d: "d" });
```